# Is there a way to use dot-files generated with Doxygen in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen

I am currently in a transition from Doxygen to Sphinx, as it looks much better and writing documentation feels better to me.

However, I am trying to include graphs generated by Doxygen in my Sphinx documentation, as the `autodoc`-extension only supports Python and the project is mostly cpp.

The project I am working on has the looks a little bit like this:

```
.
├── project
│   ├── doc
│   │   ├── doxygen
│   │   └── sphinx
│   │       └── foo
│   │           └── bar.rst
│   └── src
└── project_build
    ├── doc
    │   ├── CMakeFiles
    │   ├── Doxyfile.doxygen
    │   ├── html
    │   │   ├── doxygen
    │   │   │   └── baz.dot
    │   │   └── foo
    │   │       └── bar.html
    │   └── Makefile
    └── src
```

The problem I am having is including the dot-file created by Doxygen inside `bar.rst`. From what I understand Sphinx does not permit relative import (rightly so), which would make it rather ugly for me to include `baz.dot`. The only way I can currently see is building the project and copying the files I need from Doxygen into the project folder. What is the best/cleanest way of doing this? Because my current solution makes the documentation very static and labor intense.

Thank you in advance,

Jakob